# Error installing Perl module MIME::Lite

Tags: linux, perl

I am running Debian 9 x64 and I want to run a small script in perl which needs MIME::Lite module. To install it run this command:

> perl -MCPAN -e 'install MIME::Lite'

And this is the result:

```
    root@XutiHTPC:/home/xuti# perl -MCPAN -e 'install MIME::Lite'
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 15 Jun 2018 10:41:02 GMT
Running install for module 'MIME::Lite'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring R/RJ/RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
MIME::Lite is designed to take advantage of a variety of external modules
if they are not present then MIME::Lite will attempt to do its best
but its strongly recommend that you install them.

These modules are:
        MIME::Types
        Mail::Address
I can add these modules to the prereq list which will cause the files to be
automatically installed if they aren't already present
Add prereqs? [Yes]
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Email::Date::Format 1.000 not found.
Warning: prerequisite MIME::Types 1.28 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Mail::Address 1.62 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for MIME::Lite
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for R/RJ/RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----        RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz       ----
    Mail::Address [requires]
    Email::Date::Format [requires]
    MIME::Types [requires]
Running install for module 'Mail::Address'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MA/MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz ok
Configuring M/MA/MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Date::Format 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Date::Parse 0 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for MailTools
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for M/MA/MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz       ----
    Date::Format [requires]
    Date::Parse [requires]
Running install for module 'Date::Format'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GB/GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz ok
Configuring G/GB/GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Date::Parse
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for G/GB/GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz
  GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running install for module 'Date::Parse'
  GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/TimeDate-2.30-WvSQXd
  GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error

  MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/MailTools-2.20-noZ3M9
  MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for M/MA/MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'Date::Format => 0' for 'MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz' failed when processing 'GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'Date::Parse => 0' for 'MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz' failed when processing 'GBARR/TimeDate-2.30.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
  MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running install for module 'Email::Date::Format'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Date-Format-1.005.tar.gz ok
Configuring R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Date-Format-1.005.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Email::Date::Format
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  RJBS/Email-Date-Format-1.005.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for R/RJ/RJBS/Email-Date-Format-1.005.tar.gz
  RJBS/Email-Date-Format-1.005.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running install for module 'MIME::Types'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MA/MARKOV/MIME-Types-2.17.tar.gz ok
Configuring M/MA/MARKOV/MIME-Types-2.17.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for MIME::Types
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  MARKOV/MIME-Types-2.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for M/MA/MARKOV/MIME-Types-2.17.tar.gz
  MARKOV/MIME-Types-2.17.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
  RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/MIME-Lite-3.030-bAZrWv
  RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for R/RJ/RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'MIME::Types => 1.28' for 'RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz' failed when processing 'MARKOV/MIME-Types-2.17.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'Mail::Address => 1.62' for 'RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz' failed when processing 'MARKOV/MailTools-2.20.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'Email::Date::Format => 1.000' for 'RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz' failed when processing 'RJBS/Email-Date-Format-1.005.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
  RJBS/MIME-Lite-3.030.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
```

I've tried to install prerequisites MIME::Types and Mail::Address but no luck, MARKOV/MailTools fails.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem. Before installing any new PERL module, Linux must have MAKE installed. My debian 9 installation was fresh and make command was not installed. I ran

```
apt-get install make
```

And again the perl module

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::SMTPS'
```

And works!

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the system Perl. So why not use the pre-packaged version of the module?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmime-lite-perl
```

Comment: Oops. Stupid typo. Thanks @daxim.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it installed the MIME:Lite. Now the script is asking me for Net::SMTPS. I've tried to install it using apt-get install libnet-smtp-ssl-perl but it is already installed. and perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::SMTPS' fails too running Make. Thanks

Comment: @Xuti: `sudo apt-get install libnet-smtps-perl`. There's a pretty simple mapping between CPAN distribution names and .deb filenames.